# OCaml Syntax file for vim : '#' and '*' search

Tags: regex, vim, syntax, ocaml

I use Vim as a text editor and when I am in an OCaml source code, if I have something like this:

```
MyModule.my_function
```

if I put the cursor somewhere on `MyModule` and I press the `#` or the `*` key, Vim is going to search for `MyModule.my_function`, but I would like it to search only for `MyModule`. And if I put the cursor on `my_function`, I would like it to search only for `my_function`.

Is there a simple way to do it? I couldn't identify the regexp in the vim syntax file...

Thanks in advance,

Comment: would you like to try [Merlin](https://github.com/the-lambda-church/merlin)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What does your `:set iskeyword?` prints. If there is `.` included.

Please remove it using `:set iskeyword-=.`

Hope this fixes the issue. If so, You might like to add it in `~/.vimrc`

More details at `:h iskeyword`

Comment: It prints:  `iskeyword=@,48-57,_,192-255,.`